# For RSA, is there a specified size range for $p$ and $q$ when calculating $N$?

Tags: rsa, key-size

Is there a specified size range for $p$ and $q$ when calculating $N$? For example, what size would $p$ and $q$ be when $N$ is 1024 bits?

Comment: In general you'll have $|q| \approx |p| \approx \frac{|N|}{2}$ so in the case of $N = 1024$ you'd have $|p| \approx |q| \approx 512$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no specific length for $p$ and $q$; however, one must mind the following:

- Since $N = pq$, the size of $N$ will be more or less the sum of the sizes of $p$ and $q$ (± 1 bit).
- Security of the key relies on the difficulty of [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). The best known algorithms for that have a cost that depends on the size of $N$, but some other algorithms (in particular [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization)) have a running cost that depends on the size of the smallest factor. If one of the factors $p$ and $q$ is too small, then it may make ECM practical, leading to a security weakening.
- Private key operations with RSA can be expensive (especially on small, embedded hardware). A common optimisation is to do private key operations not modulo $N$, but modulo $p$ and $q$ (the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) tells us that it works). Since $p$ and $q$ are smaller than $N$, this is a net gain. The speed-up factor is highest when $p$ and $q$ are both about half the size of $N$.
- Some widespread implementations of RSA *require* the two factors to be exactly half the size of the modulus. This is the case, for instance, for Microsoft's CryptoAPI: when importing a private key, the import format uses fixed-size slots for the factors, that are exactly half the size of the modulus.

**Therefore**, while the [RSA standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017) does not mandate any specific sizes for the individual factors, the general practice is to make both factors $p$ and $q$ to be exactly half the size of the modulus $N$. So, for a 1024-bit modulus, the factors will be 512-bit integers.

(To be even more precise, it is customary to generate each factor with its two top bits set to 1. If you just take two 512-bit integers, their product may be a 1023-bit integer; by setting the two top bits of each factor to 1, this ensures that the product will be a 1024-bit integer.)

Comment: There is a Wikipedia note that says: For security purposes, the integers p and q should be chosen at random, and should be similar in magnitude but 'differ in length by a few digits'[2]. I don't understand why, just pointing that out.

Comment: This is to prevent recovery of $p$ and $q$ from $N$ using [Fermat's factorization method](http://facthacks.cr.yp.to/fermat.html).

Comment: About setting the top two bits to 1, do you have any links to this? I thought in computer science (not mathematics) you could have a 512 bit number where the first 100 bits were 0. It feels like you are halving your range if you say something like min = 2^511 max = 2^512, instead of min = 2^0. I did find this but its pretty informal https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195783/866502

Comment: @daniel The top bit is always 1, otherwise your 512-bit integer is not a 512-bit integer, but a 511-or-less-bit integer. The next one is explicitly set to 1 by some key generators, e.g. the one in OpenSSL, precisely to ensure that the product of two such 512-bit integers yields a 1024-bit integer, not a 1023-bit integer.

Comment: @daniel To be more precise, I make a distinction between "a 512-bit integer" (value is between 2^511 and 2^512-1), and "a 512-bit sequence" which is a sequence of 512 bits, that could start with zeros and could also be interpreted as an integer (whose size would then be _at most_ 512 bits, but possibly less).

Comment: @ThomasPornin for both P and Q? How do I fit this in with the "don't make p and q the same number of bits long" rule.

Comment: @ThomasPornin also i read your answer again and now I get why you make the minimum √2 × 2^(bits - 1) . (And you just make the key a bit or two longer to make up for it). But I don't think P and Q should be the same number of bits, digits, long.

Comment: @daniel This "don't make P and Q the same length" rule seems to be the remnants of some old advice of dubious value. The risk of having P and Q close enough to each other to allow Fermat's factorization method is much lower than the risk of making P and Q with a "special" format that allows any other factorization algorithm to become more efficient.

Comment: The advice is from here, page 9, do you have any links about making P and Q the same number of bits long being alright ? http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf

Comment: It's also the paper that says that 512-bit RSA keys should be unbreakable forever, so there's that.

Comment: I might just be getting decimal digits and bits confused, so the general advice is make them both 512 bit numbers, but not too close together, and you can probably do these two things at the same time.